# Foreach loop with a return statement

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say for example I have this function:

```
function testName($name){
  $nems = array('John','Mary','Joseph','Chuck');

  foreach($nems as $nem){
    if($nem == $name)
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

And `$name = 'Mary'`, will the foreach loop immediately terminate once `$nem==$name` or just continue finish iterating the whole array?

Answer (score 8):

It will immediately terminate.

Comment: DOH! - not at all ;-) - sorry!

Comment: What would you use to return nothing and then increment through the rest of the array?

Comment: @AlxVallejo: You can't return and *then* continue through a loop.  Once you return from a function, control leaves the function.  You can store results in a variable instead of returning, however.  I suggest looking at introductory programming books, this question is somewhat basic and should be covered.

Comment: Ya i figured it out. You just use continue. I dont need a book thanks.

Comment: I always knew it works this way, however **where is it documented?**

Comment: @DietrichEpp **no it is not** (explicitly stated there); you could say `If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function` implies that, but it does not say "it is OK to use `return` within `foreach`"

Comment: @jave.web: "If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function"--yes, this is the correct line.  I do not understand why this is not explicit enough for you, could you elaborate what you are looking for?

Comment: @DietrichEpp I am looking for an official/documented statement that says "it's OK", what **would** be enaugh would be a description of what does happen when execution of the function ends - is everything "ended" properly? Are all loops cleared? (so there is no memory hanging round and assurance that loop will NEVER be finished before ending the function (when return is called within the loop) - do you understand now better ? :-)

Comment: If that's what you're looking for, then you've found it—the linked page and the quote we're talking about give you the assurances that you want.  Reading specs and documentation like this is a bit of an art unto itself—so it's not surprising that it doesn't seem like it gives you the assurances that it does.  I'm not sure what it means for a loop to "clear", so I can't answer that part.  Memory is a separate issue from control structures.

Answer (score 3):

As @DietrichEpp said, it will terminate immediately; however I feel I need to point out that this sort of problem can be solved so very easily with a simple test script and/or referencing the manual:

[image]
<sub>(*You'll note, I didn't even need to save the file*)</sub>

Please make sure you exhaust other resources before posting.

Comment: I truly don't think this is a good answer. We need to encourage others to feel free of asking, no matter how easy or difficult the question looks for you.

Comment: @JuanJoya I think I tried to avoid being harsh (hard to remember now, it was 11 years ago) but I still stand by my answer. If the question was instead, "I ran this code, and it terminated immediately; I expected it to continue running. Why is that?", then that suggests the asker has tested their own code, and is looking for deeper understanding to why it behaves a certain way. This is just asking someone to run the code. This isn't ChatGPT. I probably voted to close, though that doesn't appear to have carried over the decade.